# PyImport_Import vs import

Tags: python, c, import

I've tried to replace

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import Pootle");
```

with

```
PyObject *obj = PyString_FromString("Pootle");
PyImport_Import(obj);
Py_DECREF(obj);
```

after initialising the module Pootle in some C code. The first seems to make the name `Pootle` available to subsequent `PyRun_SimpleString` calls, but the second doesn't.

Could someone please explain the difference to me? Is there a way to do what the first does with C API calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the `PyImport_Import` call does is return a reference to the module -- it doesn't make such a reference available to other parts of the program. So, if you want `PyRun_SimpleString` to see your new imported module, you need to add it manually.

`PyRun_SimpleString` works automatically in the `__main__` module namespace.  Without paying a lot of attention to error checking (be wary of NULL returns!), this is a general outline:

```
PyObject *main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");  
PyObject *obj = PyString_FromString("Pootle");
PyObject *pootle = PyImport_Import(obj);  
PyObject_SetAttrString(main, "Pootle", pootle);  

Py_DECREF(obj);
Py_XDECREF(pootle);
```